# Accessing npm objects in separate files

Tags: javascript, npm

I would like to use an npm package for parallax (lax.js). According to the docs, to instantiate, the following needs to be added:

```
window.onload = function () {
  lax.init()

  // Add a driver that we use to control our animations
  lax.addDriver('scrollY', function () {
    return window.scrollY
  })
}
```

I will be using lax in multiple places, and I have a separate js file to handle the functionality of each of those components. So I added the above snippet to the overarching js functionality for the whole page.

```
import lax from './lax.js';
import './component';

window.onload = function () {
  lax.init()

  // Add a driver that we use to control our animations
  lax.addDriver('scrollY', function () {
    return window.scrollY;
  });
}
```

Inside of component.js, I would like to utilize the lax object. But I get an error that lax is not defined. So I am wondering the proper way to instantiate in one file and use in another when it's a 3rd party package.

Answer (score 0):

To properly instantiate the `lax.js` package in one file and use it in another file, you need to make sure that the lax object is accessible throughout your project.

Create a `laxSetup.js` file:

```js
import lax from 'lax.js';

lax.init();

// Add a driver that we use to control our animations
lax.addDriver('scrollY', function () {
  return window.scrollY;
});

export default lax;
```

In your main JavaScript file, where you have the overarching functionality for the whole page, import and use the `lax` object from `laxSetup.js`:

```js
import lax from './laxSetup.js';
import './component.js';

// You can access and use the `lax` object here if needed for any global configurations

window.onload = function () {
  // Your existing code or additional logic
};
```

In your component.js file or any other file where you want to utilize the `lax` object, import it from `laxSetup.js`:

```js
import lax from './laxSetup.js';

// Now you can use the `lax` object in this file
// Example:
lax.addElements('.parallax-element'); // Add elements to parallax animation
lax.setup(); // Setup animations
```

Using this approach, you instantiate the `lax.js` package in the laxSetup.js file, and then you can import and use the `lax` object in any other file within your project. This ensures that the `lax` object is properly defined and accessible throughout your codebase.

Comment: I think this is importing lax. But for some reason I get an error that "window.lax" is not defined originating from lax.min.js. It does seem like the lax object exists and has properties. However trying to console.log window.lax does return undefined. Is there something in my import that would be causing this error?